# Aggregate data from Kafka using Flink

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

I am trying to write a Flink application which will read data from Kafka and increment a count in Hbase via a custom Hbase sink. I was looking into fault tolerance and I see that Flink will restart the job from the offset in the latest checkpoint. Doesnt this mean that my Hbase sink will produce duplicates? Do I have to implement my own dedupe logic?

Answer (score 0):

> Will HBase sink produce duplicates?

It depends on when you insert data into HBase.

> How to achieve Exactly-Once semantics?

According to your description, what you need is end-to-end exactly-once semantics, which means that the data can be processed more than once but the insertion can only be executed once. Take a look at the CheckpointListener interface, and the method notifyCheckpointComplete is executed when the checkpoint is completed, which is a good time for you to commit data into HBase.

For more information, take a look at this document. https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html

Comment: That is very useful, thank you! Follow up question: what is the best way to handle failures(throttling errors, temporarily unavailable errors) when writing to Hbase?

Comment: @frodo It depends on your operation. If you're doing like connecting an external dabase, it would be better if you add a retry logic. In other scenarios which may not succeed after restart, you may need to let the application crash then check it mannually.